# Writing predicates to establish an array of counts with a coredata relationships

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities in Coredata - Clients and Invoices there is a relationship from Clients to Invoices called clientInvoice. On my first tableViewController I want to list the number of invoices for each client under the client name in the cell.detail label. When a user clicks on the client cell row they are taken to the second tVC which lists the invoices of that client.

To try and get the number of invoices I am using this

```
fetchrequest
 func FetchCountInvoices() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Invoice>(entityName: "Client")
    let clientSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [clientSort]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate (format: "clientInvoice = %@  &&  year = %@ ", clients!, currentyear)
    do
    {
        let results = try context.count(for: request)
        for number in 0..<(results) {

           cInvoices.append(results)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    catch{
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

However, all I get is a crash with unexpectedly found nil... Everything I try on the predicate returns this error message. I have looked through all available answers and nothing seems to work so far. I can't believe that something as simple as this is proving to be so beyond me any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: What is `clients`? I assume force unwrapping this is what causes the crash.And your `for` loop looks weird, do you really need it since the answer should be in the `results` variable.

Comment: do you set client entity to Invoice entity as To-Many relationship?

Comment: Clients is the entity in Coredata  and yes the Client to Invoice entity is one-to many. I appreciate the comment about the loop - i don't need it. In simple terms I am looking for an array of counts (count number of invoices for each client where name = tablerow index) I am still looking through the web for this and haven't come close to solving it

Comment: Apologies clients is an instance (array) of the entity Clients